# Issue with array echo

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to output data in pdf. Upto 10 values code is working fine but it is not display 11th value and it is continuing from 12th value. Please help me fix it.

```
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM TABLE");
$Items = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $Items[] = $row;
}

$x=0;
$y=0;
$a=5;
$b=5;

require('../pdf/alphapdf.php');
$pdf = new AlphaPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$title = 'Demo';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(1.5);
$pdf->SetAlpha(1);

foreach ($Items as $array) {
if($x<5){
    $pdf->Image('abc.png',$a,$b,-300);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
    $pdf->Text($a,$b,$array['userName']);
    $a=$a+58;
    $x++;
}elseif($x>=5 && $x<10){
    if($a>290){$a=5;}
    $b=100;
    $pdf->Image('abc.png',$a,$b,-300);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
    $pdf->Text($a,$b,$array['userName']);
    $a=$a+58;
    $x++;
}else{
    $x=0;
    $a=5;
    $b=5;
    $pdf->AddPage();
 }
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I know the issue is because of the else statement that i am using but i am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If `$x > 10`, you hit the `else` statement where you're adding a new page. But you don't then actually output the 11th item, you're moving on to process the 12th instead.

Comment: try like this: https://3v4l.org/bjUGl   (use code of link)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yes it did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 11th record coming in your code, then your code goes to `else` part and there you have written code only to create a new page, nothing else. That's why 11th record got skipped.

Also you are using repeated code multiple time, which is not needed actually, try like this:

```
$x=0;
$a=5;
$b=5;
foreach ($Items as $array) {

    if($x %10 == 0 ){ // after each 10 record add new page
        $x=0;
        $a=5;
        $b=5;
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
    //add entries irrespective of pages.
    $pdf->Image('abc.png',$a,$b,-300);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
    $pdf->Text($a,$b,$array['userName']);
    $a=$a+58;
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is very quick and short solution for your this problem. You have to use less than and equal to both as well. Kindly update you code line:

```
}elseif($x>=5 && $x<=10){
```

Thanks!